# Monodroid Java Binding

Tags: java, android, binding, xamarin.android

I've created a java application to be a go between for my c# app and talking with facebook.
This helper class allows me to get friendslists and post on a facebook wall.

I've recently had some issues trying to bind one of my java functions to monodroid.

The java function I'm using follows:

```
public void PostPicture(Activity mainActivity, String opponent, byte[] bytes, String picdescription, RequestListener listener)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", picdescription);
    params.putByteArray("source", bytes);
    if(opponent != null)
    {
        params.putString("tags", opponent);
    }
    _asyncFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST", listener, null);        
}
```

The issue I'm having is trying to bind the byte[] bytes.

JNIEnv.GetMethodID(_class_ref, "PostPicture", "(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Byte;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/Hitcents/PictureThis/BaseRequestListener;)V");

Where _class_ref is my fully qualified name to the java class that contains "PostPicture".

Is [Ljava/lang/Byte not the correct binding to a byte[]?

Comment: I don't think you need the fully qualified names of every parameters. But the signature looks fine to me. "(Landroid/app/Activity;S;[B;S;Lcom/Hitcents/PictureThis/BaseRequestListener;)V"

Comment: I'm pretty sure for monodroid to bind the java you do need the fully qualified name if it isn't already built in.  i.e. integer is built in as I, but for a string you need the fully qualified Ljava/lang/String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.  By just passing the byte array through as a Ljava/lang/Object, I was then able to cast it to a byte[] on the java side.

Answer (score 1):

A `byte[]` is not a `[Ljava/lang/Byte;`, it's [`[B`](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Binding_Android_Types#Built-in_Type_References). A `[Ljava/lang/Byte;` would be a `java.lang.Byte[]` (array of `java.lang.Byte` instances).